# In directed graph find largest group such that every 2 vertexes in the group are unreachable

Tags: graph-theory

By vertexes u,v being unreachable I mean there is no path from v to u, or u to v. To summarize, we are looking for the largest group of vertexes that have no paths whatsoever between each other in the original graph.
I'm curious if there is an algorithm which finds such a group in polynomial time, or if it is possible to prove it is np-hard.

Example of such a group:
For this given graph a possible largest group would be the three numbered vertexes.

[image]

Comment: "group such that every 2 vertexes are unreachable"  What does it mean?  Please provide example of such a group.

Comment: I added an explanation and an image, hope it helps.

Comment: In your example nodes 1 and 3 are mutually unreachable because they are in separate components.  Also known as cliques, the algorithm to find the components of a graph is well known.

Comment: I think you should not focus on pairs of vertices.  From your example you seem to be looking for the largest group of vertices every one of which is unreachable from every other vertex in the group.

Comment: yes it's what I meant, I hope the edit makes it a bit clearer. I was just trying to emphasize that the group we are looking for should have no paths whatsoever between any of it's vertexes.

Comment: You can get a quick start on your group by identifying all vertices that have only in edges.   For example, in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#/media/File:Directed_acyclic_graph_2.svg nodes 2, 9, and 10